# expressjs middleware next function vs response objects next function

Tags: node.js, express

I recently noticed an undocumented `next` function on the expressjs [response](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status) object.

Is that function the same as `next` in the [middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) `function(req, res, next)` ?

Is its use discouraged because it is undocumented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [it is the same function as can be seen here in the source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/middleware.js#L23).

Yes, I would say it's use is discouraged because it is undocumented and also unnecessary since each middleware function will get `next` passed in as the 3rd argument.

Comment: FWIW, it's mainly used internally by methods like `res.render()` and `res.sendfile()` to propagate errors.